# Heating issue on i5 3570k

Tags: cooling, intel-core-i5

so I just assembled my new computer yesterday and everything was working fine apart from the fact that my CPU temps go wild.

I have an i5 3570k mounted on my Maximus V-Gene motherbord.
I'm using the stockcooler since my new one seems to be too large to fit in my case unfortunatly.

however with this stockcooler I get temps of 70°C or more when just having windows started and it does not decrease any bit.

I'm not overclocking, I left my BIOS just as I got it.

I'm so depressed right now and really do hope you guys can help me to figure out what could cause this.

Comment: Hey Tikkes. Are you sure the heatsink is seated properly on the CPU? If it's a little loose is may not work properly. (Also, I assume you haven't overclocked yet since the aftermarket cooler doesn't fit.)

Comment: How about thermal paste?

Comment: Informaficker: all the Intel CPUs I've done come with thermal paste. Is the 3570K different (no paste included)?

Comment: there was no paste included but I just got some from a friend of mine. I do believe we applied the cooler correctly but I will have another look at it when I get home.

Comment: but still...70 degrees when doing nothing at all? It topped 84 degrees when I was looking at temps in the BIOS. That's just insane.

Comment: A co-worker of mine thinks the motherboard might have issues with the heating receptors. Could this be so?

Comment: Okay so evetually figured it out. I feel so stupid right now. The problem was with the cooler. I plugged it in yesterday as I should have but then I turnet the 4 screws to where the arrow was pointing thinking it would faster the cooler. of course I only had to push it and not turn them. Hence, problem solved. Thank you all for the help you provided!

Comment: Turning them removes them. I made the same mistake with mine when I was building it ;p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stock cooler should have come with preapplied thermal paste and should look something like this [image].

Your temperatures are definitely off the charts and much higher than one would expect on an idle system. When you remove and replace your heatsink (and yeah, at this point checking if its properly installed is a good idea) see if there's a round, even smear of thermal paste on it - if its uneven, you can probably guess that the heatsink wasn't applied properly. It does not need to cover the whole head spreader.

Answer (score 1):

At idle state, 70 degrees is quite high. May be you can remove your heatsink, and try to place it again. Make sure that all four clips on the heatsink are pushed enough until they get locked with motherboard. Leaving one clip loose might result into this problem.

If this does not work, try to add some thermal paste to heatsink. Lets see if this works.

Comment: cooling paste only gives a decrease of tops 5° doesn't it? I have 70° at the moment, which is still WAY to high

Comment: Ok. By saying "apply some thermal paste", I meant "if preapplied thermal compound on heatsink has gone dry (may be due to heatsink not seated properly) then apply some thermal paste" . If preapplied thermal compound is not dry and evenly spread on heatsink, there can be other reason for the heating.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your processor is running on default clocks and with default voltage. In idle there should be (I think) about 0,9 V. Check it in CPU-Z. Also, what program are you using to check that temps? My ASUS soft shows in stress test only about 55 °C but Core Temp 1.0 RC4 shows 80°C, (but my 3570k is overclocked to 4,4 GHz and I'm not using stock cooler).

Comment: I'm using Core Temp to check my temps, also I have checked this in the BIOS which gives me the same temps. 70° or higher

Comment: check your voltage from windows, all Bios settings could be simply changed after windows boots. In my case, when I go to Bios, the CPU is NOT idle and temps are little bit higher than in Windows when idle.

Comment: I understand but still, 70° when not doing anything?